# Angular directive data binding not working inside ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is the [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/santhosh7/fsqd3fcv/). I'm trying to `ng-model` the value on click of some thing. but this value is not updating in `directive`.I tried with `$scope.$watch` also . I'm sorry for poor english and newbie to `angularjs`.

```
    <div ng-click=show()>show directive</div>
<div ng-show="afterSomeTime">
<div class="star-rating" star-rating rating-value="rating"

 data-max="10" on-rating-selected="rateFunction(rating)"></div>sdsadasdasd</div>
```

here i was trying to trigger directive after some click event but i was not able to achieve.check out that example js fiddle link

Comment: Please post relevant code in the post.

Comment: He did - there is a link to an jsfiddle example

Comment: What environment are you running in as your example works as expected for me (Chrome 50.0).

updated example with binding in ngShow - http://jsfiddle.net/wuqcnmh9/1/

Comment: @user1136560 sorry updated

Comment: @saad updated sorry for the delay

Comment: I think I had make it work, but it felt a little strange

Comment: @OwenHsieh that rating in directive is undefined.data modeling is not happening

Comment: working on the answer.

Comment: hope the answer help, I tried it on Chrome 51.0 and Firefox 46.1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from line 43

```
scope.$watch('ratingValue',
    function(oldVal, newVal) { //<-this is where you did wrong
        if (newVal) {
            updateStars();
        }
    }
);
```

Just swap `oldVal` and `newVal`, you should now make it work I believe.

Comment: ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope, search '$watch', and check the example.

Comment: thankyou for finding small bug but it took 3 hrs for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to define $scope.rating first with some initial value, then only you can bind that with directive.

```
code https://jsfiddle.net/nbakliwal18/aL7cs9je/1/
```

Comment: thank you for your answer that helped me.but still checkout other answer also that is also necessary.I think both are correct